# Wait for one node in a flow graph? / Pull-based execution?

Tags: tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I have a graph that has a few endpoints: `f0(g(x))` and `f1(g(x))`. I could make a graph with an edge from `g` to `f0` and `g` to `f1`, but if I do `wait_for_all()` it'll calculate both `f0` and `f1`. But sometimes I only want to know `f0(x)` and other times I want `f1(x)`, and sometimes I want to know both. Assuming `g`, `f0`, and `f1` are all expensive to calculate, I'd like to be able to build a graph and call `y0 = f0.run_and_wait()` and then earlier, later, or at about the same time call `y1 = f1.run_and_wait()`.

One approach is to not use a tbb flow graph and instead have `f0` and `f1` both call `g`, but that means two calls to `g`. Another approach is to have `g` do internal caching, but then if both calls to `g` happen at the same time, either both threads do the work or one thread blocks while the other does work. My understanding is that that goes against tbb's notion of non-blocking tasks.

I think maybe there's a way to use `async_node` to allow one thread to block on `g`, but that feels like a kludge.

Is there a tbb way to have nodes pull from their parent nodes on demand?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a `parallel_for` and a `task_group` there?

```
G g(const X &x);
void f0(const G& g);
void f1(const G& g);

void runAndWait(const X &x, std::initializer_list<void (*)(const G&)> functions) {
  tbb::task_group g;
  g.run_and_wait([&]() {
    G intermediate = g(x);
    tbb::parallel_for_each(functions, [&](auto &f) {
      f(intermediate);
    });
  });
}
```

The `parallel_for_each` will spawn tasks as needed. You will only call `g` once and whether it is followed by one or two calls depends on the initializer list size.

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice pattern in general. And it gets around the gotchas of `tbb::task_group`, which can be dangerous WRT exceptions.